# Typescript/JavaScript forEach

Tags: javascript, typescript1.8

I'm doing a tutorial on lexical scope handling by Typescript and I've come across the use of a function which I have never seen before. Which looks like an empty function in a forEach statement. In typescript it looks like this:

```
fns.forEach(fn=>fn());
```

In javascript it looks like:

```
fns.forEach(function (fn) { return fn(); });
```

I've never seen a function used like this. Can someone explain how this works?  To  be specific, what is fn=>fn() actually executing. In reference to the code below, is it executing the fns.push or for loop? If it is the For Loop there's no reference to this so how does it know?

Below is the full code:

**TypeScript:**

```
var fns = [];
for(var i=0;i<5;i+=1){
    fns.push(function(){
        console.log(i);
    })
}
fns.forEach(fn=>fn());
```

**JavaScript**

```
var fns = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
    fns.push(function () {
        console.log(i);
    });
}
fns.forEach(function (fn) { return fn(); });
```

Comment: What's so complicated? It executes each function in the array. However, your examples won't work, because of the closure issue. Try changing `var` in the `for` loop to `let`. Also, although not relevant to your question, arrow functions are not TypeScript specific--they are just plain old ES6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this example:

```
var method = a => a+1;
```

`method` is a var that holds a reference to a function.
`a` is the input param.
`a+1` is the methods body and return type.

Typescript will transpile this into:

```
var method = function (a) { return a + 1; };
```

Check out the [typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Avar%20method%20%3D%20a%20%3D%3E%20a%2B1%3B%0D%0Avar%20method2%20%3D%20(a%2Cb)%20%3D%3E%20a*b%3B%0D%0Avar%20method3%20%3D%20a%20%3D%3E%20a()%3B%0D%0Avar%20method4%20%3D%20(a%2Cb%2Cc%2Cd)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09var%20i%20%3D%20a%3B%0D%0A%09var%20p%20%3D%20i%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09return%20i%20*%20c%20*%20d%20-%20p%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) and you will understand the concept pretty fast.

In your example fns is an array of functions.

doing `fns.forEach(fn=>fn());` means execute each method in the fns array.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so where I am getting confused is what is the actual method is it executing? eg the For Loop or fns.push??

Comment: Ahh got it now the method is function(){console.log(i)}; That is what I was missing. Thanks for your explanation!!

Answer (score 3):

`fn => fn()` is a function definition, in C# they are called Lambda expressions and it is just syntactic sugar for the same `function (fn) { return fn(); }`.

`fn` is the input parameter, and `=>` defines it as a function and the `fn()` is the return value.

Another example is

```
var add = (a,b) => a + b;
```

is the same as

```
function add(a, b) { 
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: In this case it may be syntactic sugar, but in general it's not, in the sense that `this` and related issues are defined differently.

Answer (score 2):

It is looping through an array of functions, because functions can be stored inside variables just like strings, integers etc. So you're looping through an array of functions and executing them like this: `return fn();`